# FlatList react native not scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have made sure that the parent Views contain flex:1, and I have wrapped the FlatList in a view with Flex 1 but nothing I seem to try enables my flat list to scroll.

I have gone through previous posts and none of the solutions have worked

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code in order from parent to children

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Home />
      </AuthProvider>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1},
});
export default App;

const Home = () => {
  const [userAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);
  //{userAuth.auth && <Header title={'Stokebook'} />}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {userAuth.auth && <Profile />}
      {!userAuth.auth && <LoginHome />}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1},
});



const Profile = () => {
  const [userAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [Posts, setPosts] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);
  //Loading screen will live here

  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://192.168.1.112:3000/posts',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${userAuth.token}`,
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data.flat());
      })
      .then(setisLoading(false))
      .catch(err => setPosts(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.PostContainer}>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}
        data={Posts}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Post post={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PostContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    flex: 1,
  },
});


const Post = ({post}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.PostContainer}>
      <View style={styles.PostHeader}>
        <View style={styles.ProfileInfoView}>
          <Text>Michael Wong</Text>
          <Text>Yesterday at 6.30pm at point leo</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.WaveInfo}>
        <View>
          <Text>Wave height </Text>
          <Text> 6ft</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>tide </Text>
          <Text>low</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>Break</Text>
          <Text>crunchies</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>Wind </Text>
          <Text>NE 10km/hr</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.ImageView}>
        <Image
          source={require('../wave.webp')}
          style={{flex: 1, width: undefined, height: undefined}}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.FeedbackView}>
        <Text>
          <Icon name="thumbs-up" size={15} color="black" /> 13
        </Text>
        <Text>3 comments</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.FooterView}>
        <View style={styles.IconView}>
          <Icon name="thumbs-up" size={30} color="white" />
          <Icon name="envelope" size={30} color="white" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PostContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'beige',
    height: '80%',
  },
  PostHeader: {
    height: '20%',
    padding: '4%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  Profileimg: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  ProfileInfoView: {
    paddingLeft: '5%',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  WaveInfo: {
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    height: '12%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  ImageView: {
    height: '60%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  FeedbackView: {
    height: '10%',
    backgroundColor: 'beige',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: '3%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  FooterView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '15%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    borderBottomWidth: 12,
  },
  IconView: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '70%',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
export default Post;
```

Comment: is this all in one file?

Comment: No, each function is in its own file, and they are all exported and imported correctly

Comment: the component and styling look okay. can you share a recording of it?

Comment: I added this in Flatlist    contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
        }}